# Unable to convert BLOB to string in Java : Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to fetch and use `cursor.getString(1)` or `cursor.getBlob(1)` in my query and I have error

```
Unable to convert BLOB to string
```

The problem is when my value is `String` or let's say the value is  `null` and use `cursor.getString(1)` it works fine since the value is like string and I use getString **but** what if the value is `blob` and use `cursor.getString(1)` it errors since it conflicts, on the other hand if I used `cursor.getBlob(1)` sometimes I have a value which equals to `null` it getting me an error since the value is string is not blob

how can I prevent this? need help

**Query**

```
Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT evd.id,evd.additional_image,evd.overall_remarks FROM emv_validation_details AS evd WHERE evd.id="+id);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        myEdit.putString("emv_id_u",cursor.getString(0));
        String additional_image = cursor.getString(1);  //error here if the value is blob type
        if(additional_image ==null){
            additonal_image_u = null;
        }
        else{
            additonal_image_u = cursor.getBlob(1);
        }
        myEdit.putString("overall_remarks_u",cursor.getString(2));

    }
    cursor.close();
```

Comment: Where is the error? I see nothing.

Comment: @blackapps `Unable to convert BLOB to string` , actually there's no error if the value is blob type but sometimes when I have a value string like `null` it says ` Unable to convert BLOB to string`

Comment: What is that speaks? What is it that said such? Where do you see it?

Comment: @blackapps I have comment in my code above it says `//error here if the value is blob type` under `String additional_image = cursor.getString(1); `

Comment: Ok. The error is caused there. But we still dont know where and how you see the error. How do you know that there is an error? What does the user see?

Comment: In Sqlite, blob's can store anything so you need to retrieve the stored data in a way that does not give you exceptions, see here https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 0):

This could be an answer, if not it may give you a direction.

Try using an Object and get the return type [example here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-class-in-java/)

Don't know if it will work first up, you may need to tweak it but, I can't test it but you won't know if you don't try.

```
Object additional_image = "";

if((additional_image = cursor.getString(1)).getClass().toString() != null)
{
    //TODO whatever
}
```